# Computed verilog parameter in Yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am learning Verilog at the moment by using Yosys to synthesize code to an iCE40 development board. I am stuck at using parameters in verilog. I have the following code:

```
module tst;

    parameter clkspd=12000000;
    parameter baudrate=115200;
    localparam bitperiod=$floor(clkspd/baudrate-0.5);
    localparam bittmrwidth=$clog2(bitperiod);
    //localparam bittmrwidth=$clog2(103);

    initial begin
     $display("Hello World!");
     $display("width=%d",bittmrwidth);
    end

endmodule
```

When I compile the code with :

```
yosys -p 'synth_ice40 -top tst -blif tst.blif' tst.v
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Failed to evaluate system function `\$clog2' with non-constant value at tst.v:5.
```

However if I use the commented out line, everything work as expected.

How can I calculate "bittmrwidth" with the given parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have `yosys` installed, but when I run your code on another simulator, I get this error:

> System function call $clog2 must have an integral argument.

This is consistent with the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 20.8.1 *Integer math functions*, which states for `$clog2`:

> The argument can be an integer or an arbitrary sized vector value.

The `$floor` function returns a `real` result type, according to section 20.8.2 *Real math functions*.  Simply cast the `$floor` output to an integer type with `$rtoi`.  The following code runs without errors for me:

```
module tst;

    parameter clkspd=12000000;
    parameter baudrate=115200;
    localparam bitperiod = $rtoi($floor(clkspd/baudrate-0.5));
    localparam bittmrwidth=$clog2(bitperiod);

    initial begin
     $display("Hello World!");
     $display("width=%d",bittmrwidth);
    end

endmodule

/*

Output:

Hello World!
width=          7

*/
```

My original code used a cast operator, but apparently `yosys` does not yet support it, according to the Comment below.  Here was my original line:

```
localparam bitperiod = int'($floor(clkspd/baudrate-0.5));
```

Comment: This. However, Yosys does not support much SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800), only Verilog (IEEE Std 1364). The support for `$rtoi` and `$itor` was still missing, but I've now added it in commit [dfb461f](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/commit/dfb461fe5213ec649f384f1e1dbd6d58d5763910). Maybe you want to edit your answer to use `$rtoi` instead if `int'`, so it is applicable to Yosys.